# Negative value when using the Outlier Labeling Rule

Tags: outliers

I think I have some outlier values in my data set so I'm using the Outlier Labeling Rule (Hoaglin, D. C., Iglewicz, B., and Tukey, J. W. [1986]. Performance of some resistant rules for outlier labeling. *Journal of the American Statistical Association*, 81, 991-999). 
However, in some cases when I use this method, I get a negative value for my lower bound cut-off point. How is this to be interpreted as negative values don't occur with my measures (physiological measures e.g. cortisol levels).

Comment: It sounds as if (a) no value is less than lower quartile - 1.5 IQR (b) that is also a value that could not be reported. No problem; certainly no outlier lower than the median. With data like yours, and generally,  outliers are most likely among high values; but any values that are physiologically (biochemically, whatever) impossible or implausible or imply that the patient is dead or moribund should be checked too, as possible recording errors. (In one famous dataset posted in an online library it took a sharp analyst to flag multiple zeros for blood pressure, presumably a code for missing.)